# Synchronisation Service doesn't update Job Title

Tags: 2010, user-profile, user-profile-service, synchronisation, forefront

A user's Job Title field isn't updating in the User Profile (and therefore an old value is showing-up in the People Search).

Interestingly, I can see the Job Title property changing when I view it in the Forefront Synchronisation Service:

[image]

... but it's not updated in the User Profile:

[image]

What could be the issue here? Forefront fails to complete the transaction? The user record has an error? (I not the manager value is now blank).

Comment: is it for only one user? did job title change effect the user id? also did you run the full crawl of UPS and also full crawl for people search?

Comment: Seems to be happening for other users as well. The property is definitely mapped properly: "title to Job Title".

Comment: did you run full crawl & full sync?